# If a team member is pulling for the first time, is this considered a fetch (since there is presumably no merge involved) or a pull?

Tags: git, github

I apologize, I am new to Git/GitHub and want to ensure I am communicating an idea correctly to others.  If I have a brand new team member, who needs a fresh copy of the code in our repo (from head) would I asked them to "fetch" or to "pull" it?  Since this is their very first time taking the code, I could see them only needing to fetch:

```
"Hey John please fetch the code."
```

Would they still need to merge locally though?  If this is the case, I would need to say this:

```
"Hey John please pull the code."
```

I don't know which one of these is correct.

---

On a side note, is "code" the correct term?  Maybe I should say one of these instead:

```
"Hey John, please pull/fetch the repo."  
"Hey John, please pull/fetch the master branch."
"Hey John, please pull/fetch head on the master branch."
```

Comment: Shouldn't they just *clone* the entire repo?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a pull is just a combination of a fetch and a merge. Unless you are quoting an exact command, whatever verb you use should be reasonably interpreted as cloning the repository.

Comment: Technically, when you run `git pull` in a repository with no commits, it doesn't run either `git rebase` *or* `git merge` as its second command. It runs the equivalent of `git checkout`. In the bad old days, it ran an equivalent that destroyed all the work-tree files you didn't commit yet; I got burned badly by this once. I always recommend that those new to Git *avoid* `git pull`, in favor of the two underlying commands, so as to get used to what the two commands do, and when to use them. After they're comfortable with the components, *then* you can introduce the "does it all for you" button.

Comment: The big reason for that is the "does it all for you" button hides the two components. Some might argue that this is a good thing, but in fact, the second step often goes wrong. It's important to know how to recover from that, and the *how to recover* part depends on *which* second command you used!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask them to clone the repository. This will fetch all branches and tags. Then you would instruct them to checkout a particular branch. You can also checkout a specific branch when cloning

```
git clone [-b BRANCH] <URL>
```